# HOWTO Export/Import custom code snippets in XCode 6

Tags: xcode6, code-snippets

Is there a way how to export the custom code snippets from XCode 6 and then import it to the XCode 6 of another user?

The snippets are now in one XML file: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/SystemCodeSnippets.codesnippets`
Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In Xcode 7.3.1, my snippets have been created in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/CodeSnippets`.  It looks like you may be in the wrong directory.  Put your codes snippets in this directory instead.

On a side note, you can find my code snippets here: [XcodeSnippets GitHub](https://github.com/jfosterdavis/XcodeCodeSnippets)

Comment: The path to the CodeSnippets directory is still valid as of Xcode 9

Comment: ...and the path is still valid today for Xcode 12.4